# How to associate a browser with winrar?

Tags: windows-xp, browser, winrar

Every time I open an archived animated .gif it pops up in Internet Explorer. How do I make Firefox the default viewer for this type of files? Going to options, settings, then viewer tab and choosing the browser did nothing. Any suggestions?

Comment: What OS do you use ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 7, go to Set Associations (search for it in the Start Menu)

[image]

If you are using XP, follow the instructions [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_2052279_change-file-type-associations-windows.html).

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention I'm on XP.

Comment: Okay, will post on how to set file associations in XP anyway.